# Is there a way to assign categories before the articles are added via the Aggregator module?

Tags: 7, feeds

I'm interested to aggregate posts with the built-in Aggregator module.

My problem is that it's not possible to assign a category at the same time. Users have to later find the post and manually set the category.

Is there a way to to assign categories when the post is created?

Answer (score 3):

The aggregator is for importing feeds from other sites, but it sounds more like you're trying to create new feeds on your site from your content. For that use, you could use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views).